# How to use unique_ptr for arrays

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, move-constructor

I have a class

```
class A {
public:
  A(){cout<<"C";}
  ~A(){cout<<"D";}
};
int main(){
  unique_ptr<A> a(new A[5]); // - doesn't work 
  unique_ptr<A> a(new A[1]); // - doesn't work
  unique_ptr<A> a(new A); // - works
}
```

Why does this happen?

I guess that the thing is about the move constructor (it cannot be created automatically because of the destructor), but why do we need a move constructor here?

And what's the difference between:

```
unique_ptr<A> a(new A[1]); // - doesn't work
unique_ptr<A> a(new A); // -works
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `A` and `A[]`?

Comment: Please *never* write "doesn't work", that's useless. Either it is failing to compile (what error message?) or it is crashing (where according to the debugger?) or it is producing an unexpected result (which one, and what was expected?), etc.

Comment: The question title is horrible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use `unique_ptr` with an array allocation, you need to use a specialization of it:

```
unique_ptr<A[]> a(new A[5]);
```

Comment: I know, but I just wanted to know why this code works, when I remove destructor from class A.

Comment: It doesn't, because not all the destructors will get invoked.

Comment: I've just tried this code with commented destructor and it printed "CCCCC"

Comment: "C" is the constructor, which will get called by `new[]`.

Comment: I know, I'm saying that this unique_ptr<A> a(new A[5]); printed "CCCCC"

Comment: My comment about not working is not about the constructor, but about the destructor when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.

Comment: when there was destructor there was segmentation fault and when I deleted destructor it printed something ("CCCCC"). I just wanted to know why it didn't work with destructor and printed something without it.

Comment: Because deleting an object allocated with `new[]` with `delete` (instead of `delete[]`) leads to undefined behavior. It shouldn't really matter to you beyond that.